# What is the difference between explicate and expound?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, verbs, differences

I googled it and got the following answer:  As verbs the difference between explicate and expound is that explicate is to explain meticulously or in great detail; to elucidate; to analyze while expound is to lay open; to expose to view; to examine or exposit. 
I still don't understand it.

Comment: Hi @link and welcome to ELU. Can you please give the weblink for the definitions? For what purpose do you need to know the difference between 'explicate' and 'expound'? For instance, do you need to include the terms in a report or research study? Best wishes

Comment: HI @JulieCarter :) I found the definitions here: [link wikidiff.com](http://wikidiff.com/explicate/expound) I read the words in some news article and I wanted to know how I could use them in my writing in the future.

Comment: Thanks @link and I'm glad you've been provided with a useful answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1984) includes *explicate* and *expound*—together with *elucidate*, *interpret*, and *construe*—in a group under the heading word *explain*. Here is its treatment of *expound* and *explicate*:

> **Expound** implies careful, elaborate, often learned setting forth of a subject in order to explain it (as in a lecture, a book, or a treatise) {a clergyman *expounding* a biblical text} {*expound* a point of law} {Sir A. Eddington in two masterly chapters ... *expounds* the law of gravitation—*Alexander*} {*expound* the duties of the citizen} **Explicate**, a somewhat learned term, adds to *expound* the idea of development or detailed analysis {the mind of a doctor of the Church who could ... explicate the meaning of a dogma—*T.S. Eliot*}

An earlier edition of *Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942) has an identical treatment of the two words, except that also says that *explicate* means "literally, to unfold."

S.I. Hayakawa, *Choose the Right Word* (1968), on the other hand, groups explicate with *elucidate*, *explain*, and *interpret* under the heading word *clarify*, but doesn't address *expound* at all. Here is Hayakawa's commentary on *explicate*:

> **Explicate** is more restricted and specific in use than the foregoing [*clarify* and *elucidate*]. It refers to a point-by-point discussion of a complex matter, especially as in the paraphrase and analysis of a literary text: asking each student to *explicate* the difficult poem; popular books that attempt to *explicate* Einstein's theories.

Putting the two discussions together, I would surmise that, although both terms imply a carefully developed (and usually, scholarly) investigation and presentation of a subject, *explicate* has a stronger sense of a line-by-line or point-by-point analysis of the subject, whereas *expound* is just as learned but perhaps a bit more general in its treatment and more inclined to elaborate on the implications of the broader subject.

Comment: thanks a lot! > `explicate has a stronger sense of a line-by-line or point-by-point analysis of the subject, whereas expound is just as learned but perhaps a bit more general in its treatment and more inclined to elaborate on the implications of the broader subject.`

Answer (score 0):

"Explicate" from the Latin *ex* (out) + *plicare* (to fold), means to make clear and intelligible.  "Expound" from the Latin *ex* + *ponere* (to put) means to explain.  It's possible to **expound** (put your explanation out to an audience) but not so clearly that you **explicate** the matter (unfold the meaning) for your listeners.